# Как лучше всего логировать ошибки JavaScript на сервере?

Tags: javascript

Как лучше всего логировать ошибки JavaScript на сервере?

Comment: Полностью контролировать ошибки путем `try {} catch (e) {}` синтаксиса, дабы страницы не переставали отвечать

Comment: Логировать куда и лучше с какой точки зрения?

Answer (score 2):

Если быстро что-то проверить, то можно использовать `console.log()`
Либо подключить сторонние логгеры.

Comment: Вопрос не о console.log(), а о логировании ошибок JavaScript на сервере.

Comment: Подразумевается использование NodeJS?  Если да, то существует много log модулей https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/logger. Опишите, пожалуйста, детальней задачу - попробую подобрать подходящее решение.

Answer (score 1):

- Подписаться на window.onerror.
- Ajax'ом отправить ошибку вместе со stacktrace'ом на сервер.
- Залогировать пришедшую ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы браузер клиента уведомил о случившейся ошибки нужно обращаться за помощью к ajax-запросам или к WebSocket, которые будут срабатывать в качестве обработчика какой-либо ошибки (исключения).